# UAC dialog when changing windows settings windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, administrator, uac, desktop-computer

Each time I change a windows setting in control panel that requires admin a UAC (User account control) dialog pops up and this did not happen before. I am the main administrator on the computer and I have already checked the UAC settings and they are set to notify me when I install a program and not changing windows settings. I don't know why this is happening. Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of an Update which was released this Patchday. [Uninstall](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/remove-update#1TC=windows-7) the Update [KB3004394](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3004394/en-us), this [causes the UAC issue](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/windows-update-kb3004394-issues/ace25277-7f65-4486-bc44-c1b106907a18) under Windows 7.